# Meraki's Accounting-Requests to RADIUS server

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, radius, access-point, freeradius

I'm running a RADIUS server with some Meraki APs, the process of Authentications is fine... But it seems that the Meraki Cloud Controller is just sending the authentication packets and not the accounting requests. I've tested the RADIUS sending accounting requests with the radclient tool (locally) and it worked.

I think that maybe my RADIUS server is ignoring the accounting requests from the MCC because there are some Vendor Specific Attributes that my RADIUS doesn't know. should I add a Meraki's dictionary to my RADIUS configurations?

I'm kind of desperate, any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the configuration for Accounting in the MCC is hidden by default (there are two separate configuration: Auth and Accounting) . You have to talk to Meraki's support and ask them to enable it.

Answer (score 2):

run the radsniff utility that is included in the standard set of utilities, to verify that the server is actually receiving the accounting packets (or start the daemon debug mode -X). FreeRADIUS will not ignore well formed VSAs even if it does not have the dictionaries to decode them.